# Hibernate Tuning SessionFactory Cache

Tags: performance, hibernate, caching, sessionfactory

I'd like to optimize some Hibernate code.

I try to tuning Hibernate and Spring, 
I wonder if it's right if I only have to add the hibernate cache property "true":

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
```

and I have the SessionFactory defined in Spring ("aop.xml")   :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/hibernateCode</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And finally I try to use the LazyDataModel, the method implemented:

```
@Override
public List<EnvioMensual> lazyLoad(
        final int index,
        final int count,
        final String sortField,
        final boolean sortOrder,
        final Map<String, String> filters,
        EnvioMensual filtro) {

    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EnvioMensual.class);

    if (sortField != null && !sortField.isEmpty()) {
        if (sortOrder) {
            criteria = criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(sortField));
        } else {
            criteria = criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(sortField));
        }
    }

    if (!filters.isEmpty()) {
        final Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = filters.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
            criteria = criteria.add(
                    Restrictions.like(
                            entry.getKey(),
                            entry.getValue(),
                            MatchMode.START
                    )
            );
        }
    }

    criteria = criteria.setFirstResult(index).setMaxResults(count);

    return criteria.list();
}
```

The queries get correctly parameters :

```
final Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(EnvioTraspaso.class);
    if (criteriosFiltrado.getFechaCreacion() != null
            && !criteriosFiltrado.getFechaCreacion().equals("")) {
        final Calendar criterioFecha = criteriosFiltrado.getFechaCreacion();
        final Calendar fechaMinima = CalendarUtils.getFechaMinima(criterioFecha);
        final Calendar fechaMaxima = CalendarUtils.getFechaMaxima(criterioFecha);
        final Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();
        and.add(Restrictions.ge("fechaCreacion", fechaMinima));
        and.add(Restrictions.lt("fechaCreacion", fechaMaxima));
        criteria.add(and);
    }
```

Thanks Amir!! I have tests that take a very long time to respond, then I need to fix my code this way:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Set<NotificacionSISNOT> filterBySujeto(final Sujeto sujeto, final int start, final int limit, final String orderBy) {
    final Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
    criteria.add(Restrictions....
            ...criteria.setFirstResult(start)
    .setMaxResults(limit)
    .setCacheable(true)
    .setCacheRegion("sisnotpages");

    return new LinkedHashSet<NotificacionSISNOT>(criteria.list());
}
```

It's correct ?

Comment: First, if you are using a data-source, then remove `hibernate.connection.pool_size` attribute, cause it won't work! (You shall configure pool size in your data-source config).

Comment: If you want to cache criteria's result cache (if you don't know how hibernate caches queries, read docs), you shall call `criteria.setCacheable(true);` before executing it.